# How to increase slider values in whole numbers when starting value is 2 decimals

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a price slider that submits and works as it should. The only thing it doesn't do is increase the values of the slider in whole numbers when the starting value is a 2 decimal number.
It also doesn't display the initial 2 decimal number. Just to show what I mean here is the code:

```
 $Deposit= '12.85'; 
<script>
   Deposit_increase = <?php echo (isset($_GET['Deposit_increase'])) ? 
   $_GET['Deposit_increase'] : 0 ?>;


   $(document).ready(function() {
   $( "#slider-range-min" ).slider({
      range: "min",
      value: <?php echo $Deposit ?>,
      min: <?php echo $Deposit ?>,
      max: 3000,

      values : [Deposit_increase],
                slide : function(event, ui) {
                    $("#Deposit_increase").val(ui.values[0]);
                },
        change: function() {
            $("#increase_form").submit();
        }
    });
    $("#Deposit_increase").val($("#slider-range-min").slider("values", 0));
});
  </script>
```

The form:

```
 <form action="" id="increase_form" method="get">

           <p  style="margin-left:12%; color:#2872bd; font-weight:bold; text-align:left">
  Change your Depost<br><br>
Deposit: £
  <input type="text" id="Deposit_increase" name="Deposit_increase"  style="border:0; color:#2872bd; font-weight:bold; text-align:left"  value="<?php echo $_GET['Deposit_increase']; ?>">

</p>    
        <div id="slider-range-min"></div></form>
```

Here it displays as follows:
Deposit: £12.9  (instead of £12.85)

The slider uses increments of 1 so all values will be shown as 13.9, 14.9. 15.9 etc.

What I want the slider to show is:
14, 15, 16 etc.

Is there a way to achieve this? Any help welcome

Comment: Are you try [`Math.floor`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwii7f7226bUAhXDpI8KHbr9BrYQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FMath%2Ffloor&usg=AFQjCNGL37JEZnhpaPio8R0D-c_w9lusdg&sig2=19Cej_qCmu5U9ScEuJKiRQ)?  and [`Math.round`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round)

Comment: You will have to use [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) or something similar to get your value to be an integer as step is doing what it should aka `1.01 + 1 = 2.01`

Comment: @prasad I'm not sure how to do that, is it possible to apply that to the slider as well?

Comment: Please add a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) to help show your problem

Comment: @Ria I m not sure .try this `Math.round(<?php echo $Deposit ?>)` for value and min

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace the following line

```
$("#Deposit_increase").val(ui.values[0]);
```

with

```
$("#Deposit_increase").val(Math.floor(ui.values[0]+0.5));
```

This will always round off to the nearest integer.

Comment: This works partly, The slider submits the values as whole numbers (which is what I wanted, however the displayed value is still Deposit £XXX.5.

Comment: Interesting use of `Math.floor`, would just be easier to use `Math.ceil`

Comment: @George if I am not mistaken, it would not yield the same result. Ceiling would only return the upper bound always. Using with an addition of 0.5 would actually round it off always.

Comment: @RajeevRanjan You are correct, but when working with money you normally always round up otherwise you'll be underpaid or underpaying tax, and the tax man cares about those 0.5p.

Comment: I changed the following as well: $("#Deposit_increase").val(Math.floor($("#slider-range-min").slider("values", 0)+0.5)); so now the deposit shows as a whole number as well. Thanks for your help

Comment: Welcome Ria. Do check your use case as @George mentioned in which case a plain Math.ceil() would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the increment function in your code, but you should be able to raise the slider value using the Math library.

You can do this by listening the slider input value and transforming this value before it gets displayed again.

```
var newVal = Math.ceil(val);
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use either Math.round() for this situation

Math.round will round your value to the nearest whole number